# How can I execute linux system commands at same time in C++ by assigning each command to threads?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, networking

I want to execute to different network commands which show same output by assigning them to two different threads, they should execute in parallel and using c++

Comment: Can you use C++11? What have you attempted?

Comment: Yes using system(" ") command I'm executing linux system commands through my c++ program, now I want to assign two different system commands like system("ping---") and system("ifconfig") to two different threads executing parallely.........HOW should I do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with thread and things @Borgleader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point using threads for this problem, because the only way to execute an external utility ("linux system command") is to `fork()` a child process and then `exec()` the utility.

Since you cannot `exec()` inside a thread -- it would replace the entire process, not just the thread in which it is called -- you might as well just go with the flow and use multiple processes.

You can create as many child processes as you like (within reason) and `exec()` a different external command in each one. The various processes will run independently.

Comment: I have to capture network statistics of using two different commands at same moment of time. That's why I'm asking for solution.

Comment: @gauravkodande: There are code examples all over the internet. Here are a few which might be useful: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/simple_system.c.html, http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/multi_wait.c.html, http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/procexec/system.c.html

Answer (score 1):

You can execute inside a thread, if this is on unix which I am assuming you can make a function, call pthread_create and pass it that function.  Inside that function just do a system_call.  Then do pthread_join on the thread ids pthread_create returns, and wait for it to return.  Then you know its done executing, and can exit, or go on with your program.  Similar things will work on windows as well.